# Archiving JSON events from RabbitMQ to S3

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, rabbitmq, logstash, messaging

I have a process publishing JSON events to a RabbitMQ exchange. I'd like to attach a consumer that both groups the events and then archives them to S3 in a sensible, buffered, and compressed manner. Specifically, given an event `{"id": "1a2b3c4d5e6f", "ts": 1439995475, ... }`, I'd like it to end up in at an S3 key effectively looking like `%Y/%m/%d/%H/1a2b3c4d5e6f.json.gz`, where the datetime components of the string are derived by flooring the timestamp to some time interval, e.g.:

```
new_ts = Math.floor(event["ts"] / SECS_PER_HR) * SECS_PER_HR
```

This seems like a relatively common problem, so while I could, I'm disinclined to write my own solution. It's pretty much a messaging pattern, and indeed it seems like a lot of log management technologies should be able to handle this.

Specifically, I was looking at a Logstash solution. It seemed like there could be a relatively simple pipeline:

- RabbitMQ input adapter
- JSON filter adds `ts` and `id` tags
- S3 output adapter buffers them and rolls them off. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html)

Still, I'm confronted with several issues that I'm not savvy enough with Logstash to address.

- To my knowledge, there's no way for Logstash to perform either the timestamp math or the more abstract alternative of grouping by timestamp
- The S3 plugin provides no utilities for more elaborate key name templating (which is relatively important because this data will be programmatically accessed)
- There doesn't seem to be any way of adding compression to the S3 plugin's output
- Most problematic of all, there doesn't seem to be any logic for merging files -- understandably, the S3 plugin keeps its life simple by making sure keynames are always unique, thus avoiding merging.

Am I asking too much of logstash here, or is there some way that it can fill my purposes? Is there another third party solution that addresses my needs (it certainly seems like there should be!)? Or do  I have to resort to my own devices here?

Comment: I can't speak to the s3{} output specifically, but you can always use the ruby{} plugin to do the date manipulation.